# React route went missing after refresh

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm pretty new to React.js and I've a problem with react routes.

There are three routes, `/, /profile, /profile/edit`. When I try to refresh /profile/edit, it goes blank with this error in the console: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrrqL.png)

from what I understood from the errors, there is a syntax error with these js files which are build files  !!!

Here is my router code:

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => this.renderPage()}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/profile"
            component={() => this.renderPage()}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/profile/edit"
            component={() => this.renderPage()}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is the code for renderPage:

```
  renderPage() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
```

this works until I refresh the /profile/edit page as I mentioned above. this error only shows when the app is deployed, it works fine in localhost.

Any help ?

Comment: What is `this.renderPage`? Does it return renderable JSX? Try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. You've got the minimal part down, but we need more code for context and ability to "step" through and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese Edited. Also, this issue only shows when deployed

Comment: this >>> ```component={() => this.renderPage()}``` is not a good practise. Instead try ```component={this.renderPage}```

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with `renderPage` not being an actual react component, though I am sure a `Route`'s `component` prop can take and handle anonymous functions. Can you test by creating a `const TestComponent = () => <div>test</div>;` and change the routes to render `component={TestComponent}`? Also, where is your app deployed to?